# Can i pass data between functions in codeigniter?

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter

im loading a simple form as a subview, i need to pass the data to the next function but when I use `$this->data`i get a blank page. here is my controller:

```
 <?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Search extends Admin_Controller {


    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
        $this->load->helper('form');
        $this->load->model('search_model');

    }
    function index()
    {

        $this->data['subview'] = ('../views/user/search_form');
        $this->load->view('../views/_layout_admin', $this->data);
    }
    function execute_search()
    {
        // Retrieve the posted search term.
        $search_term = $this->input->post('search');

        // Use a model to retrieve the results.
        $data['results'] = $this->search_model->get_results($search_term);

        // Pass the results to the view.
        $this->data['subview'] = ('../views/user/search_results');
        $this->load->view('../views/user/search_results', $this->data);

    }
    }
```

Any help/ideas? much apreciated

Comment: hi, i think you need to read all codeigniter´s doc, because when you load a view in `application/views/...` you dont need to use `$this->load->view('../views/---` only `$this->load->view('views/...` Then, when you send **$data** to view you need to is `$this->load->view('../views/view_tamplate', $data);` as a documentation

Comment: what are you using $this->data why not just $data?

Answer (score 0):

you can also just load your sub view by in your main view doing:

```
<?php $this->load->view('user/search_form'); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Replacing your controller by this code:

```
 <?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Search extends Admin_Controller {


    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
        $this->load->helper('form');
        $this->load->model('search_model');

    }
    function index()
    {

        $data['subview'] = ('../views/user/search_form');
        $this->load->view('layout_admin', $data);
    }
    function execute_search()
    {
        // Retrieve the posted search term.
        $search_term = $this->input->post('search');

        // Use a model to retrieve the results.
        $data['results'] = $this->search_model->get_results($search_term);

        // Pass the results to the view.
        $data['subview'] = ('../views/user/search_results');
        $this->load->view('search_results', $data);

    }
    }
```